# electron reduce nsis installer size | x64 only

Tags: electron, 64-bit, electron-builder

The common problem - my simple app has size of 54mb in nsis installer. I need to reduce it, maybe to 30-35mb. I read that nsis generates both x32 and x64 in the same file, maybe I could generate only x64?

My package.json (only win):

```
"win": {
  "icon": "build/icons/icon.ico",
  "target": [
    {
      "target": "nsis",
      "arch": [
        "x64"
      ]
    }
  ]
},
"nsis": {
  "oneClick": false,
  "perMachine": false,
  "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
  "artifactName": "${productName}-${version}-Setup.${ext}"
},
```

I'm running Windows 10 x64.

Comment: So, the upper code generates only x64 version. There's no way to reduce installer size.